# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_bugs" already exists

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

After I deleted all the migration files and made them again using "python3 manage.py makemigrations" and "python3 manage.py migrate", the following error occurred:

```
root@chat-manager:/var/www/jinabot# python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, app, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0002_auto_20220604_2133...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "app_bugs" already exists


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 92, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.create_model(model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 331, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 145, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "app_bugs" already exists
```

How to fix it?
..................................................................

Answer (score 0):

In database, the relation has already been created. You might have two references for bugs relation in your django app models.py file. If you find multiple reference please rename it differently.

If it's isn't the case you can resolve the error in 2 days:

1. Delete database entirely. If you're using sqlite3 db then just delete db.sqlite3 file present in your project directory.
2. Delete all migrations file entirely and recreate and apply it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).